# Create Excel with string values

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I would like to create an excel with string rows in it.Now by default the excel creates numeric rows and the value i want to set is 00000111.the code i am using is the following :

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object

oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "0000111"
oSheet.Range("B1").Value ="Name"
oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Name2"
oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "Phone"

oBook.SaveAs("C:\New folder\excel\" & datenw & ".xlsx")
oExcel.Quit()
```

Kind Regards ,
Ifigenia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the number format for the cell to Text. So need to add a line in your code.

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object

oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

oSheet.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"    'This is the added line
oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "0000111"
oSheet.Range("B1").Value ="Name"
oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Name2"
oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "Phone"

oBook.SaveAs("C:\New folder\excel\" & datenw & ".xlsx")
oExcel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way

Change

```
oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "0000111"
```

to

```
oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "'0000111" '<~~ Notice the ' before the number
```

Comment: Damn.. beat me by 2 seconds :-)